# Error GET in the $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I receive this error

> GET
>
> http://zz33.infoucrso.com/WSCategoria.svc/insertarCategoria?callback=jQuery191011035312712192535_1435768698856&Nombre=hjn&_=1435768698857
> b.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5b.extend.ajax @
> jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5Calcular @ funciones.js:3onclick @ index.html:11

This is a web service that receive a parameter but I really don't know what is happening. I need help!

Comment: It looks like the problem stems from your `funciones,js` file - do you know which line of this file the debugger is complaining about?

Comment: I guess....because when I debug I put a req.success and doesnt send the message of success...so I think that the problem maybe is here: var req = $.ajax({
          url : 'http://zz33.infoucrso.com/wss/WSCategoria.svc/insertarCategoria?callback=?',
          dataType : "jsonp",
          data: { Nombre: v1},
          timeout : 10000
        });

Comment: And is strange because that work with the example that my teacher send me....but I try with my example and doesn't work .....